# Sum up values in excel based on multiple conditions

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an excel worksheet which captures hours spent by resources for tasks for each work day. The input sheet looks like this -

[image]

I need to pull a report based on this data to gather number of hours filled by each resource on each day between a date range (specified by a start and end date). Sample output looks like this -

[image]

I have tried using `SUMIFS` but it fails to give me an output as the row/column range for all conditions and the sum range needs to stay same, which is not same for my case.

Can someone suggest an alternative to get required data?

Answer (score 0):

`SUMIF` will work for you but you need a dynamic sum range.
This bit can help you achieve that:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$9,$A15,INDIRECT(CHAR(64+MATCH(B$14,$A$1:$G$1,0))&"2:"&CHAR(64+MATCH(B$14,$A$1:$G$1,0))&"8"))
```

Most important part is `CHAR(64+MATCH(B$14,$A$1:$G$1,0))` which searches position of your date and converts it into column name.
I used `2` and `8` as indicator for the beginning and end of sum range and wrapped everything with `INDIRECT` to convert string to cell reference.